# NullPointer exception when scaffolding first Grails app

Tags: grails

Starting out with Grails I have installed Grails version 2.4.0 and using JDK 1.7.0_55 on GNU/Linux I do the sequence of actions below but keep getting a NullPointerException. Can someone provide a pointer to what I am missing or doing wrong ?

```
grails create-app firstgrails

cd firstgrails

grails

grails> run-app
```

I go to localhost:8080/firstgrails and see the generated page.

Next I do

```
grails> create-domain-class tag
```

and go to the firstgrails/grails-app/domain/firstgrails folder and edit Tag.groovy so it contains:

```
// Tag.groovy
package firstgrails

class Tag {
    String name
    String description
}
```

Next

```
grails> create-controller tag
```

and edit firstgrails/grailsapp/controllers/firstgrails/TagController.groovy into

```
// TagController.groovy
package firstgrails

class TagController {
    static scaffold = Tag
}
```

I do a reload in the browser and firstgrails.TagController is added to the list of available
controllers under the welcome message. Selecting it, I create a tag with name and description and the tag shows up in the list of tags as expected. But now whenever I try to add a second tag I get an 500 error: Internal Server Error with

```
URI: /firstgrails/tag/create
Class: java.lang.NullPointerException
Message: null
```

The trace in the console is:

```
 Error 2014-06-03 18:28:31,714 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /firstgrails/tag/create
Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:form>: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
    Line | Method
->>  527 | doFilter  in /tag/create
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:form>: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
->>   35 | doCall    in /tag/create
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
->>   30 | doCall    in /tag/create
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by NullPointerException: null
->>  333 | hash      in java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    988 | get       in     ''
|    141 | getValue  in grails.util.CacheEntry
|     81 | getValue  in     ''
|     73 | doCall .  in tag_create$_run_closure2_closure24
|     78 | doCall    in tag_create$_run_closure2
|     81 | run . . . in tag_create
|    189 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2014-06-03 18:30:33,050 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /firstgrails/tag/create
Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:form>: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
    Line | Method
->>  527 | doFilter  in /tag/create
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:form>: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
->>   35 | doCall    in /tag/create
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
->>   30 | doCall    in /tag/create
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by NullPointerException: null
->>  333 | hash      in java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    988 | get       in     ''
|    141 | getValue  in grails.util.CacheEntry
|     81 | getValue  in     ''
|     73 | doCall .  in tag_create$_run_closure2_closure24
|     78 | doCall    in tag_create$_run_closure2
|     81 | run . . . in tag_create
|    189 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2014-06-03 18:32:21,796 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /firstgrails/tag/create
Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:form>: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
    Line | Method
->>  527 | doFilter  in /tag/create
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:form>: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
->>   35 | doCall    in /tag/create
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
->>   30 | doCall    in /tag/create
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by NullPointerException: null
->>  333 | hash      in java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    988 | get       in     ''
|    141 | getValue  in grails.util.CacheEntry
|     81 | getValue  in     ''
|     73 | doCall .  in tag_create$_run_closure2_closure24
|     78 | doCall    in tag_create$_run_closure2
|     81 | run . . . in tag_create
|    189 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Doing the exact same thing with version 2.3.9 of Grails, everything is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this and able to reproduce it. If we generate view then it is resolved but without views it is giving error. There is an issue in `grails` `jira`, see [this issue](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11430) they have provided a patch for it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Confirmed that adding `generate-views firstGrails.Tag` within the `grails> ` prompt, as an extra action, resolves the issue.